# Proving a result on Spectral Radius - proof verification

Tags: numerical-methods, normed-spaces, solution-verification

I am taking a first course on numerical methods and wanted to prove the below result on spectral radius. I would like to ask if my proof is correct.

> We are given that, if $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $\vert \vert A \vert \vert_2 = [\rho(A^TA)]^{1/2}$.
>
> Prove that if $A$ is a symmetric matrix, $\vert \vert A \vert \vert_2 = \rho(A)$.

*Proof.*

(1) Let $\lambda$ be the eigenvalue of the matrix $A$ corresponding to the eigenvector $x$.

$\begin{align}
Ax &= \lambda x \\
(A^T A)x &= \lambda A^T x \\
&= \lambda Ax \space \text{...($A$ is symmetric)} \\
&= \lambda^2 x
\end{align}$

So, $A^T A$ has the eigenvalues $\lambda^2$ corresponding to the eigenvector $x$.

(2) By definition, the spectral radius of $(A^T A)$ is $\rho(A^T A) = \max \vert \lambda \vert^2$.

(3) Let $x$ be an arbitrary vector of length $1$. $\vert \vert x \vert \vert_2 = 1$.

$\begin{align}
\vert\vert A \vert\vert_2 &= \max_{\vert\vert x \vert\vert_2=1} \vert\vert Ax\vert\vert_2 \\
\vert\vert Ax\vert\vert_2 &=\left(\sum_i (Ax)_i^2\right)^{1/2}\\ 
&= \left( (Ax)^{T} (Ax) \right)^{1/2}\\
&= \left( x^T A^T A x \right)^{1/2}\\ 
&= \left( \lambda^2 x^T x \right)^{1/2}\\ 
&= \left( \lambda^2 \vert \vert x \vert \vert_2^2 \right)^{1/2}\\ 
&= \lambda
\end{align}$

From (2) and (3), we have :

$\vert\vert A \vert\vert_2 = [\rho(A^T A)]^{1/2}=\max \vert \lambda \vert$ = $\rho(A)$

and

$\vert\vert A \vert\vert_2 =\max \vert\vert Ax \vert\vert_2$ = $\max \vert \lambda \vert$

Comment: (minor typo) You forgot an absolute value when taking the sqrt of $\lambda^2$

Comment: In point (1), you show that if $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$, then $x$ is also an eigenvector of $A^\top A$ (with eigenvalue $\lambda^2$). You have not shown that every eigenvalue of $A^\top A$ is of this form.